# html button CSS resize to fill div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have read several similar questions, all involving use of width and height attributes either inline or in a class. However no matter how I seem to try it, it is not working.

Due to wanting to apply transformations to the button and text independently, I have had to use a class on the div and a sub class for the button. Stripping the code down, the width and height of the button are not filling the surrounding div.

I am working in Visual Studio 2008 and debugging against IE8 if that makes any difference.

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
        <tr>
            <td >
                <h1>&nbsp;TITLE</h1>
            </td>
            <td style="width:150px;height:40px;">
            <div class="button-wrapper">
            <button ID="RetrieveButton2" title="tooltip" runat="server" serverclick="RetrieveButton_Click">Search</button>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
}

.button-wrapper
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
}

.button-wrapper button
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
```

Comment: Did u check it in Google Chrome.. Cause I jus checked it n acc to what I have seen button covers its div button.wrapper..

Comment: Looks fine on my IE, it is taking up 150x40 pixels of space...

Comment: It's working in every browser (including IE7 and 8). See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abDVh/. What browser(s) are you testing in (name and version)?

Comment: I am testing it in IE8, launching from within a Visual Studio 2008 debugging session.

Comment: Is this all your CSS, or you have something else inside it (other rules)?

Comment: This was everything. I started a new project in VS2008, put in only what was necessary to test this (the above html and css), and hit debug, and it exhibited the same behaviour as my full codebase. I am guessing this is a VS bug, I will deploy the full codebase somewhere tomorrow and check if it works outside VS.

Comment: Perhaps it's something VS is doing: -either adds something to your CSS, or -it creates a new HTML button element instead of what you have added in your HTML code.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a `<button>`, not an `<asp:Button>`? There's a difference; asp:Buttons are not buttons, so the CSS wouldn't work.

Comment: @MrLister no, the code above is using a button and had the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be environmental. It was not happening on deployment, but it is all academic because requirements have changed so no longer using this code.